# How i can assign to user with specific role in azure ad?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, middleware

In .NET Core web app i have different user roles (Admin, User), based on that i want to show different pages using Azure ad app role.

How i can assign user with specific role to azure ad app?

Currently i am getting user roles from database using Middleware approach because of that number of of API calls.

Comment: Hello did you tried the solution? Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a user to that application, in one of the specified app roles, you'll need to set the `appRoleAssignment` on the user. If you are using Microsoft Graph API, you could use below rest API :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/cde330e5-2150-4c11-9c5b-14bfdc948c79/appRoleAssignments
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization: Bearer {token}
{

  "principalId": "9028d19c-26a9-4809-8e3f-20ff73e2d75e",
  "resourceId": "8fce32da-1246-437b-99cd-76d1d4677bd5",
  "appRoleId": "498476ce-e0fe-48b0-b801-37ba7e2685c6"
}
```

- **principalId** :The id of the client service principal to which you are assigning the app role.
- **appRoleId** :The id of the appRole (defined on the resource service principal) to assign to the client service principal.
- **resourceId** : Service Principal ID of the application. To get service principal id , you could use below API (`objectId` claim):

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{your resourceId}
```

If want to filter then:

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}&$filter=appId eq 'appid'
```

**Note:** You can check the official document for [details information on service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

**Get appRoleId:**

You can get the [app role `Id` by calling below Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$select=displayName, appId, appRoles&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'App-Name')
```

[image]

[image]

**Note:** For further details you could check our [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Md Farid Uddin Kiron answer using the graph C# library. (For assigning users to approles in azure)

PrincipalId: The id of the client service principal to which you are assigning the app role. => (aka The object Id of the user which you want to assign the permission to)

ResourceId: The id of the resource servicePrincipal (the API) which has defined the app role (the application permission) => (aka the id of service principal of the application that your roles have been defined, it's object Id)
Locate via REST

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}&$filter=appId eq 'appid'
```

Or locate `on portal.azure.com => Azure Active Directory => Enterprise Application => Select your application => Overview => ObjectId`
[Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehp0q.png)

AppRoleId: The id of the appRole (defined on the resource service principal) to assign to the client service principal.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider ); 
var resourceId = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["00ea0040-e0028-00aa-0000-aa00a0cd000"].Request().GetAsync();
var principalId = await graphClient.Users["youruser@email.com"].Request().GetAsync(); 
var appId = resourceId.AppRoles.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Equals("specificRole", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

//perform checks on your variables above before passing below

```
var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
{
   PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(principalId.Id),
   ResourceId = Guid.Parse(resourceId.Id),
   AppRoleId = appId
};
                

await graphClient.Users[principalId.Id].AppRoleAssignments
      .Request()
      .AddAsync(appRoleAssignment);
```

Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).